# Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim(V)=n$ and $S$ be an infinite generating set of $V.$ Show that there exists $H\subset S$ such that $H$ is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim(V)=n.$ We assume, $S$ to be an infinite generating set of $V.$ Prove that there exists $H\subset S$ such that $H$ is a basis.

I tried to solve this as follows:

To prove this claim, we pick a non-zero element in $S$ and put it in a set $H$ and then, we examine each and every element of $S$ and add it to $H$ only if, addition of that element does not make $H$ a linearly dependent subset of $V.$

This process, must terminate after some $k$ steps, as the number of elements in any linearly independent subset of a finite dimensional vector space is less than or equal to $\dim(V).$ So, $|H|\leq n.$ If $|H|=n$ then from a corollary of Replacement theorem, we can say, that $H$ is a basis for $V.$ If $|H|<n$ then again, from a corollary of Replacement Theorem, we can extend the set $H$ to make it a basis.

---

However, I feel my proof is a bit incorrect.

- This is because, in one part, of the  proof I said, that:

> This process, must terminate after some $k$ steps, as the number of elements in any linearly independent subset of a finite dimensional vector space is less than or equal to $\dim(V).$

While, the fact that any linearly independent subset of a finite dimensional vector space is less than or equal to $\dim(V)$ is true, but, we can't be  sure about the process terminating after some finite number of steps. This is because, it might so happen that after some $pth$ step, we start examining remaining elements of $S$ and find that none of them can be added to $H.$ We thus, continue this examination. The point is, if say, none of the remaining elements of $S$ can be added to $H$ then, the searching process won't ever stop,as we go on searching until we find another element in $S$ whose addition in $H$ retains it's linearly independentness. So, we can never stop after any finite number of $k$ steps. The searching process then continues indefinitely.

This is just one problem. The next problem is:

- In the last line of my proof I write,

> If $|H|<n$ then again, from a corollary of Replacement Theorem, we can extend the set $H$ to make it a basis.

This is true, but then we never specify whether the elements that are  added to $H$ to make it a basis for $V$ are added from the set $V$ or from the set $S.$ If the elements are added from the set $S$ then this proves our claim definitely. But say, if one element is added from $V$ such that it is not in $S$ then this newly form basis $H$ is definitely not a subset of $S.$ This does not prove our claim then.

---

I need some help in fixing these apparent issues. Otherwise, if my proof is correct, I want to know, why these two "issues" I stated explicitly above are not any issues in reality.

Comment: Why do you require that $S$ is infinite?

Comment: @PaulFrost I already know that this holds true when the generating set was finite.

Comment: Then why don't you use the fact that the statement is true when $S$ is finite?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ha ha, if I were able to do that, my problem wouldn't been solved! But unfortunately, I couldn't use that fact to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the OP was able to prove the correctness of the statement when $S$ is finite.

We consider the other case, i.e when $S$ is infinite.

Take a basis  $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $V$. For each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $e_k$ can be written as a linear combination of a finite subset $S_k$ of $S$. Let $S^\ast=\bigcup_{k=1}^nS_k$. Then, since $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ spans $V$ and since each $e_k$ is a linear combination of elements of $S^\ast$, $S^\ast$ spans $V$. But $S^\ast$ is finite, and therefore it contains a basis of $V$. So, since $S^\ast\subset S$, $S$ contains a basis of $V$.

Comment: Ok, but how do you know, whether or not every $e_k$ can be written as a linear combination of a finite number of vectors in $S.$ It might very well be true that $e_k$ is   a linear combination of an infinite subset of $S$.

Comment: In Linear Algebra, there is no such thing as a linear combination of infinitely many vectors, unless all the coefficient  except for finitely many of them are equal to $0$. But then, we will be dealing with a linear combination of finitely many vectors.

Comment: Wait, but it might be very well true that, $e_k$ is written as a linear combination of the vectors in $S$ such that an infinite number of coefficients of the vectors in the linear combination is non-zero?

Comment: No, that can't be true. It doesn't make sense. Again: in Linear Algebra, when we have a linear combination of elements of a set, only finitely many coefficients can be different from $0$.

Comment: Are you suggesting that when we say, that "a vector $v$ in $V$ is a linear combination of the vectors in a subset say, $W$ of $V$" then, we mean that "*$v$ can be written as a linear combination of a finite number of vectors in $W$*" or in other words, when $v$ is written as a linear combination of the vectors in $W$ then only a finite number of  coefficients of the vectors (of $S$ ) in this linear combination is non-zero ?

Comment: No, I am not suggesting that at all. I am *asserting* it.

Comment: So my previous comment is a general fact of Linear Algebra? To specify again: when we say, that "a vector $v$ in $V$ is a linear combination of the vectors in a subset say, $W$ of $V$" then, we mean that "*$v$ can be written as a linear combination of a finite number of vectors in $W$*" or in other words, when $v$ is written as a linear combination of the vectors in $W$ then only a finite number of  coefficients of the vectors (of $S$ ) in this linear combination is non-zero. --- This is what the phrase  "$v\in V$ is a linear combination of vectors of a subset $S$ of $V$ "

Comment: means in Linear Algebra, right? Sorry, if I sound annoying but I am really eager to get clarity on this. I am surprised because I never knew this previously!

Comment: I will be really very obliged and grateful, if you consider responding to my comments although, i admit that I might sound repetitive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148276/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-thomas-finley).

Answer (score 1):

Your idea almost works. Here's how you can make it work.

First set $H_0=\varnothing$. Now for each $i\ge 0$, if $H_i$ is defined and there is $v\in S$ which is *not* in the span of $H_i$, set $H_{i+1}=H_i\cup\{v\}$, otherwise set $H_{i+1}=H_i$. By recursion, this defines an infinite sequence
$$H_0\subseteq H_1\subseteq H_2\subseteq\cdots\subseteq S$$
By induction, each $H_i$ is linearly independent and if $H_i=H_{i+1}$ then $H_i=H_{i+j}$ for all $j\ge 1$. It follows that $H_n=H_{n+1}$, because otherwise $H_{n+1}$ contains $n+1$ linearly independent vectors, contradicting $n$-dimensionality of $V$. But by definition of $H_{n+1}$ this implies that the span of $H_n$ is the span of $S$, which is $V$, so $H_n$ is a basis.

Comment: This approach shows that the assumption that $S$ is infinite does not play a role.

Comment: I am just coming back here after (finally) returning to Hoffman and Kunze with a somewhat better understanding of set theory and some fundamentals. If I am understanding you correctly, you are using the (or a) recursion theorem to define a map $f: \Bbb N \to P(S)$ with the given properties. You are then saying that, with this map $f$ fixed, you can prove by induction the claims you make?

Comment: @EE18 Yes that's right.

Comment: Many thanks again for all your help!