# Hoffman and Kunze on basis extension theorems

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

Hoffman and Kunze give the following theorem:

> **Theorem 5.** If $W$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, every linearly independent subset of $W$ is finite and is part of a (finite) basis
> for $W$.

Their proof begins as follows (I do not supply the full proof, because I follow that. I am only confused about why they choose the following tact.)

> *Proof.* Suppose $S_0$ is a linearly independent subset of $W$. If $S$ is a linearly independent subset of $W$ containing $S_0$, then $S$ is also a linearly independent subset of $V$; since $V$ is finite-dimensional, $S$ contains no more than $\dim V$ elements. [Therefore, $S_0 \subset S$ contains no more than $\dim V$ elements]. *Continued...*

My question is why the introduction of $S$ was at all necessary. That is, why couldn't we argue as follows:

> *Proof.* Suppose $S_0$ is a linearly independent subset of $W$. Then $S_0$ is also a linearly independent subset of $V$ (because it's a subset of $V$); since $V$ is finite-dimensional, $S_0$ contains no more than $\dim V$ elements. *Continued...*

HK are usually very precise, so I'm sure the introduction of this $S$ matters, but I can't tell why on earth it should be so.

---

P.S., HK give the following corollary to the theorem:

> **Corollary 2.** In a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ every non-empty linearly independent set of vectors is part of a basis.

Why do they specify "non-empty" here? Can't we say *any* l.i. subset is part of a basis (more precisely, "can be extended to a basis") of $V$ simply by setting $W = V$ in the theorem? I don't see why the empty set can't be extended to a basis as per Theorem 5.

Comment: What is the span of the empty set? Remember, subspaces are vector spaces. Can a vector space be empty?

Comment: @JohnDouma The span of the empty set is the zero subspace.

Comment: Yes, as blargoner says, the span of the empty set is the zero subspace $\{0\}$. This can be shown in various ways, but probably the easiest is the characterization of span as the intersection of the set of all subspaces containing the given set of vectors. @JohnDouma

Comment: @blargoner It is if we define the span as the smallest vector space containing the set. Does the author define it that way or does he define it as the set of linear combinations of the vectors in the span? I have seen both.

Comment: @JohnDouma You get the zero subspace either way if you consider an empty linear combination (sum) to be the zero vector, which is a standard convention.

Comment: @JohnDouma The author defines it as the former but shows equivalence to the latter (and, thank you for pointing this question out since as blargoner says, I should have noticed that the proof of that equivalence of span definitions depends on the convention of how the empty linear combination is defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They introduce $S$ because of what happens later in the proof as they build a sequence
$$S_0\subseteq S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq\cdots\subseteq W$$
of linearly independent subsets by successively adjoining to $S_i$ a new vector $\beta_{i+1}$ not in the span of $S_i$, for as long as possible. Taking $S=S_i$ we see that this process must eventually stop in at most $\dim V$ steps. Your revised proof would only cover the first step.

Regarding the corollary, the use of "non-empty" is what I call *fear of zero* -- perhaps anticipated on the part of the reader. The empty set is linearly independent according to their definition, and the corollary is still true for the empty set, so it's not needed.

Comment: By the way their proof is somewhat informal. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4762993/129912) for a more precise statement of a similar proof.

Comment: Thank you re: "fear of zero". That resolves that part of the question. I'm afraid I don't follow the first answer though. Can you elaborate? The first part of the proof seems intended to prove the "very linearly independent subset of $W$
 is finite". Then (it seems to me, evidently incorrectly) that the second part of the proof (which I did not include here) is intended to prove the "is part of a (finite) basis for $W$" claim. I don't see how the second part relies on the first part at all?

Comment: @EE18 It's all part of one argument. They're giving an informal, hand-wavy algorithm for extending the given linearly independent set to a basis. The issue is, how do we know that the algorithm halts after a finite number of steps, and we don't just get infinitely many linearly independent vectors? The answer is, because of what must be true of *any* linearly independent set $S$ (containing the given set).

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking at HK (I think from your answer you are but, if not, let me know if not and I can supply more info) but when they remark "(in not more than $\dim V$ steps)" in their proof, I simply added "else we obtain an l.i. subset of length larger than $\dim V$, contradicting Corollary 2a on HK page 45". I don't see how I've used the $S$ introduced earlier here?

Comment: @EE18 I'm not saying you can't write a different proof that does different things. I'm trying to explain to you why they introduced $S$ in their proof, and why the revised proof you wrote in your question above was incomplete by itself.

Comment: Totally got you, I guess I'm just trying to understand what (or rather how) HK are arguing here. When they say "(in not more than dim $V$ steps)", are you saying that they are arguing that, if we take each $S_i$ as the earlier $S$ (since $S_i$ contains $S_0$ and is a subset of $W$), then $S_i$ contains at most dim $V$ elements. Thus it follows that the process stops at or before $i = \dim V$, for otherwise (by construction of $S_{i+1}$) we will have a linearly independent subset of $W$ with more than $\dim V$ elements, contradicting what we just said about $S_i$ having at most size $\dim V$?

Comment: @EE18 Right, that's the idea.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the perseveration, I just wanted to make sure I understood what HK were doing.